failed sqlite3 query query in ejs
when making a get request in my webapp, this error appears on the rendered ejs page
posts.forEach is not a function
    at eval (eval at compile (D:\code\MERN apps\sql express ejs multer\ciel\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:673:12), <anonymous>:15:14)
    at profile (D:\code\MERN apps\sql express ejs multer\ciel\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:703:17)
    at tryHandleCache (D:\code\MERN apps\sql express ejs multer\ciel\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:274:36)
    at exports.renderFile [as engine] (D:\code\MERN apps\sql express ejs multer\ciel\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
    at View.render (D:\code\MERN apps\sql express ejs multer\ciel\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (D:\code\MERN apps\sql express ejs multer\ciel\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
    at Function.render (D:\code\MERN apps\sql express ejs multer\ciel\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (D:\code\MERN apps\sql express ejs multer\ciel\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1048:7)
    at Statement.<anonymous> (D:\code\MERN apps\sql express ejs multer\ciel\index.js:97:21)

this is the code that creates the table
//database table
 db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT, description TEXT, imagepath TEXT)');

this is the code that executes when the get request is made
//GET REQUEST
 db.get('SELECT * FROM posts', (err, rows) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send('Error fetching data from table2');
                }
                responseData.posts = {posts: rows};

                // Send the combined response
                res.render('profile', responseData);
            });

multer initialization
//MULTER
const upload = multer({dest:'uploads/'});`

this is the code in the ejs page
`//EJS OUTPUT
 <% posts.forEach(post => { %>S
       
       <li><%= post.title %> </li>
       <img src="<% post.imagepath %>">
       
     <% }); %>

i made a post request to put data into the table, but i still get the same error message
//POST REQUEST
app.post('/createpost', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    const title = req.body.title;
    const description = req.body.description;
    db.run('INSERT INTO posts (title, description, imagepath) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [title, description, req.file], (err) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send('Error making post');
        }
        res.redirect('/profile');
    });
   
 });


Well, the error message basically says that the posts variable doesn't have a forEach() function, which could either mean that it's undefined or a different kind of type than you think. From what I can see, you set the posts property of the responseData variable to {posts: rows}. I hope you declared the responseData variable somewhere as an object. Then you pass the responseData object to the render method, but in the template you use posts.forEach(...) which, obviously, is not defined. Use responseData.posts.forEach() instead, since posts itself is never declared!

To be honest, it doesn't make much sense how and what kind of variable you pass to the res.render() function. As a db response object, rows should be an array, and therefore you could simply say res.render('profile', {posts: rows}); and that way (as long rows really is an array) you can work with the posts.forEach() method in the template.
